# Adding a wildcard function to an excel array formula to return multiple values vertically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, wildcard

I'm designing a stopgap solution for querying a large Excel spreadsheet that was an import of file share list.  I've been able to draft the search function to return multiple rows matching the exact criterion, but the requirement is now to have the criterion be a wild card; example: 81301* or *301904.

Here is the base formula(s) I'm using:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ANAQUADATA!$G$2:$G$6316, SMALL(IF($D$3=ANAQUADATA!$A$2:$A$6316, ROW(ANAQUADATA!$A$2:$A$6316)-ROW(ANAQUADATA!$A$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"" )

=IFERROR(INDEX(FileLink, SMALL(IF($D$3=TradeMarkID, ROW(FileLink)-ROW(ANAQUADATA!A2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"" )
```

Any help with injecting a wildcard functionality to the existing formula would be great!!!

In advance, thank you
Michael

Comment: `...IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$3,ANAQUADATA!$A$2:$A$6316)),...`

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Craner!  Will test now and respond back with result(s)

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!  Works like a charm!!!!  Thank you, Scott!  I hope to repay the favor and guidance some day.